# String will not write to output correctly

Tags: c++, string, ofstream

I am trying to write to a file and am having trouble with the string not writing.

From what I have been able to figure out, my string will only print if I place a '\n' after it. The problem is I am trying to write it to a file and it has to be all in line with other information.

Sample of what I am trying to make my file look like:

```
1111 Last, First   10     20      $30.00
```

What it actually writes:

```
1111               10     20      $30.00
```

This is what i have tried and it will only print the last 3 items. If I place a '\n' after *getName()* then it prints everything fine:

```
    ofstream outputFile("somefile.txt");
    outputFile << std::setw(10) << getAccount() 
               << std::setw(10) << getName() // returns a string
               << std::setw(10) << getNum1()
               << std::setw(10) << getNum2()
               << std::setw(10) << getTotal() << endl;
```

I have tried calling flush after *getName()* but it did not work

```
    outputFile.flush()
```

I am supposed to store the last and first name separately.

```
    string getName() const
    {
        string full = last + ", " + first;
        return full;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you trying to *print* or write to a file? And what does "it did not work" mean? What *precisely* did you do? What did you expect? And what happened? It sounds like you want `outputFile << getAccount() << getName() << getNum1() << getNum2() << getTotal() << std::endl;` maybe.

Comment: You have to outputFile.open("somefile") first?

Comment: I updated my question to make it a little clearer. 

The problem is it will not display the string for the name unless I place a '\n' right after getName().

Comment: Why would it ever display anything? I thought you were trying to write to a file?

Comment: Sorry, I meant it will not write to the file. It is just blank where the name should be.

Comment: You'd really need to show us the `getName` function for us to do anything other than randomly guess.

Comment: Make sure your `getName()` doesn't return a string ending in `'\r'`! Your description seems to indicate that your string contains a carriage return causing the characters which are actually there to not be visible as they are overwritten by characters coming later.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I added in my function. Could the '\r' be picked up from the text file that I am getting my data from?

Comment: @mrT: yes. It depends on how you open the input file, on what system you are, and how the file was written: for example, if you try to read a typical Windows file on UNIX you'll have that problem. You can also have that problem on Windows when opening the file in binary mode. Just check for a `'r'` in your `std::string` using a statement like `if (str.find('\r') != str.npos) { ... }`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thank you! That was my problem, just ran the code again and it found the '\r' in the strings. So now I have to figure out how to eliminate them.

Comment: @mrT: just use `str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());`

Comment: Try replacing the function calls in your output statement with strings that you assign before the output statement.  This will allow you to set a breakpoint before the output statement and verify the content of each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you actually specify a name for the output file, e.g.

```
std::ofstream outputFile("some-file.txt");
```

Assuming this is sorted, have a look at `std::setw(n)` from `<iomanip>` and make sure your outputs are somehow separated. For example, you might want to use

```
outputFile << std::setw(8) << getAccount() << ' '
           << std::setw(20) << getName() << ' '
           << std::setw(6) << getNum1() << ' '
           << std::setw(6) << getNum2() << ' '
           << getTotal() << '\n';
```

... and if you really want to make sure the output is immediately written to the file rather than buffered:

```
outputFile << std::flush;
```

(which is equivalent to `std::outputFile.flush();` but using cuter syntax).

Based on comments mentioned above, I would *guess* you ended up with names containing a `'\r'` right at the end: this way, it looks as if there is nothing but actually the characters are just overwritten by characters coming later. You can remove the carriage return characters using

```
str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), '\r'), str.end());
```